# How to upload very large files to FTP server with pause and resume? Similar to Rsync

Tags: ftp, file-transfer, rsync, sftp

I'm trying to figure out what is the best way to upload files to an FTP server with a pause / resume feature.

Also, more importantly, I'm looking for a tool that might help with handling an issue where the internet disconnects in the middle of the transfer (As this might happen as the files are very large). From what I understand rsync works however it does not work for FTP.

Any ideas? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Handling disconnects and pausing transfers are two different things, imo. Anyway, I believe most FTP clients can resume transfer after disconnects.

(My) WinSCP can do that. FileZilla can do that too.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use rsync it would be better than ftp, I don't believe out the box you can resume ftp connections. What platform are you using? I think there are commercial products on the windows platform winscp.
If you can you use rsync
This should help you.

Transfer a file over an unstable SSH connection

http://https:/https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193378/transfer-a-file-over-a-unstable-ssh-connection

```
rsync -av --partial sourcedir user@desthost:/destinationdir
```